# Artinian rings are perfect

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

**Definition.** A ring is called *perfect* if every flat module is projective.

> Is there a simple way to prove that an Artinian ring is perfect (in the commutative case)?

Comment: It depends on the definition you take of perfect ring: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring gives several equivalent ones.  If you take e.g. the one in which DCC holds on principal ideals, there is certainly nothing to show.  So what's your definition?  Also, I find Lam's two GTMs on ring theory to be an excellent reference for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The local case is proved [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/051E), Lemma 10.97.2, and then extend the result to the non-local case by using that an artinian ring is isomorphic to a finite product of artinian local rings and a module $M$ over a finite product of rings $R_1\times\cdots\times R_n$ has the form $M_1\times\cdots\times M_n$ with $M_i$ an $R_i$-module.

Comment: The local case is not proved there. What is proved is the case where the ring is local with a nilpotent maximal ideal.

Comment: @RobertGreen A basic fact about artinian rings (even non commutative) is that their Jacobson radical is nilpotent.